# Migrating from eclipse ADT to Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, eclipse-adt

I have Updated my sdk and all things gone wrong
my Appcompat v7 and play services libraries are giving errors without any reason.

I cannot build my project to gradle 
is there any easiest way to move my project to android studio without gradle project?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to worry about gradle.

Install any extra libs, sdks that you want.

Download/install AS 1.0.1 to somewhere in fileSys where you have RW privledges, and then get used to AS by just clone a git project like [this](https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterialEverywhere)

go to AS and follow "import non AS project" giving the folder of where you cloned the git proj.

Gradle builds on this cloned and imported project should just work ..... no gradle knowledge reqd.

then go back to your Appcompat V7 guy with the issues and try to import it as non AS .. the IDE will make a copy of the orig proj. and it should sync and build OK. Gradle wrapper stuff will be handled as part of the import process so you dont have to immediately know all kinds of gradle build trivia.

In long run , if u do android , you're going to need to pick up gradle. this